# Regex matching exactly 1 of a specific character(s)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match `@relRef` but not `@@absRef` from:

```
Stuff @relRef more stuff @@absRef
```

From what I understand, `[^@]@{1}[^\s]*` should work, but it's still incorrectly selecting both.  Does `{1}` not mean what I think I does?  (I think it means "match the previous thing exactly 1 time")

`[^@]@[^@][^\s]*` does work, but it's less convenient for my use case and more importantly, I don't understand why my original solutions doesn't work.

Finally, does whatever this answer ends up being change if it's multiple characters.  (i.e. if the sentence is `Stuff AT_relRef more stuff ATAT_absRef` so now I'm not checking a single @ character but "AT" instead.)

**tl;dr:**

1) Why does `[^@]@{1}[^\s]*` match `@@absRef` and how do I fix it to only match `@relRef`?

2) Does the answer to #1 change if I'm using more than a single character to mark the reference?  (i.e. `AT_relRef` and `ATAT_absRef`)

Comment: Also, see the [**regex**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) tag info page: *Using `{1}` as a single-repetition quantifier is harmless, but usually an indication of inexperience and/or confusion.* Probably, this is not the best wording, the meaning is *`{1}` is just redundant as each pattern atom / part without an explicit quantifier behind it is tried at least once.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches both because `[^\s]` that matches any char but whitespace will match the `@` char, too. The `[^@]` matches a space in both cases, so it is not helpful enough. Also, `@{1}` is the same as `@`, the `{1}` quantifier is always redundant in any regex.

You may use

```
(?<!@)@[^\s@]\S*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s43wUN/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!@)` - no `@` right before the current location
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[^\s@]` - a char other than `@` and whitespace
- `\S*` - 0 or more non-whitespace chars.

As for the second case, a negative lookbehind will work, too:

```
(?<!AT)AT_\S*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s43wUN/2). It matches

- `(?<!AT)` - any location not preceded with `AT`
- `AT_` - an `AT_` substring
- `\S*` - 0+ chars other than whitespace.