# Regular expression to match X with only ONE of a given Y before it (up to the start of the string)

Tags: regex

I have data where fields may be literal values, or tables denoted by curly braces, similar to Lua syntax:

```
a = 4

b = {

}
```

I need a way to determine if the first field of the text is a table or not. To do this, I need to determine if there's some `{`, which is preceded by exactly ONE `=`, and no more. A second `=` would signify we've already passed a field that is not a table.

Negative lookbehinds seem to still match unless the `=` is IMMEDIATELY before the match. So this is capturing b's brace:

```
={1}\s+{
```

EDIT: Regarding the supposed duplicate [Regex matching exactly 1 of a specific character(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244200/regex-matching-exactly-1-of-a-specific-characters)

This question is asking how to make a regex match '@something' but not '@@something', i.e. only allow a single preceding '@'. My question is about finding an '=' ANYWHERE in the preceding string, not necessarily immediately before the match. So that: `= blahblahsomething {` will match the '{', but `== blahblahsomething {` will give no matches.

Comment: What language/tool/platform/framework are you using?

Comment: You could try [`^(?<!\s)[^=]*=\s*{`](https://regex101.com/r/5hbc1T/1)

Answer (score 1):

To limit the preceding chars to exactly one `=`:

```
^[^={\n\r]*=[^={\n\r]*\{
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/hnbFKA7Fy8G6xK).

`{` is in the negated character class to ensure it's the *first* `{` with exactly one `=` preceding it.

Line ending chars added to ensure the match is all on one line.

Comment: Thanks, but I gave this a try here https://regex101.com/r/xff3WS/1 and it doesn't seem to do what I need. In the case where the first field 'a' ISN'T a table, I don't want it to have any matches.

Comment: @ThomasSlade line endings catered for - see edited answer.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xff3WS/1 Still makes the match when it shouldn't, and it's not knon for sure if the opening brace will always be on the same line as the declaring field.